# Package does not exist error though i have imported it

Tags: java, compiler-errors, directory-structure

I have a directory structure com/example/web with BeerSelect.java file in it.

### BeerSelect.java

```
package com.example.web;

import com.example.model.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse     response) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    ArrayList<String> brandsFromExpert = new ArrayList<String>();

    BeerExpert expert = new BeerExpert();

    String c = "light"

    brandsFromExpert = expert.getBrands(c);
}
}
```

And I have another file in the directory com/example/model with BeerExpert.java file in it.

### BeerExpert.java

```
   package com.example.model;

   import java.util.*;

   public class BeerExpert{

   public List getBrands(String color)
   {
    List<String> brands = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(color.equals("amber"))
        brands.add("JacK Amber");
    else
        brands.add("Jail Pale Ale");

    return brands;
   }
  }
```

[image: Directory Structure]

But when I try to compile the BeerSelect.java I get the following error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Can anyone please tell why?

Comment: Why are you importing `com.example.web.*;` in your `BeerExpert` class? Maybe this is causing a problem with compiling the dependencies.

Comment: hi. you notice fast. :)  For testing purpose I tried that out. But even without that it does not work bro. Just when I finished editing it I saw your comment.

Comment: Add the directory "classes" to your classpath argument.

Comment: Java is not able to detect that package itself... You may have to include your `src` folder in the class path.

Comment: Elliott & CodeBender. Can you guys please share the terminal command to do the same here in the comments

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. Waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You should be *in* the `src` directory when you compile, and you should name the file(s) to compile as `com/example/`... whatever.

Because you posted a picture of your output instead of the text it is impossible to provide a more accurate answer.